# AS3 TextField: Append text at a certain line?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield, appendtext

I'm trying to find a way to append text (appendText) at a certain `TextField` line number.

I found a way to return the first character of a line:

```
tf.text.charAt(tf.getLineOffset(10)); //selects line 10
```

But I haven't found a way to append text. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (put the supplied text at the start of the supplied line), though there may be a more efficient way of doing it.

```
function prependToLine(textField:TextField, line:int, text:String):void {
    var lineOffset:int = textField.getLineOffset(line-1);
    textField.text = textField.text.substring(0,lineOffset) + text + textField.text.substr(lineOffset);
}
```

Comment: thanks! was just trying substring now..cheers for helping me out